# Is there any easy way to replace %20 by a space in a CString?

Tags: string, mfc

I need to replace some %20 by spaces and got compile errors which i do not understand:

```
CString str = _T("foo%20bar");
str.Replace('%20',' '); // C4305 argument: truncation from 'int' to 'wchar_t'
str.Replace(_T('%20'),_T(' ')); // C4305 argument: truncation from 'int' to 'wchar_t'
str.Replace(_T("%20"),_T(" ")); // C2664 'int ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>>::Replace(const wchar_t *,const wchar_t *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [4]' to 'wchar_t'
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CString::Replace()` method takes null-terminated string pointers as input, not individual characters. Your string literals need to use `"` instead of `'`, eg:

```cpp
CString str = _T("foo%20bar");
str.Replace(_T("%20"), _T(" "));
```

Note that matches your last example, which you say is also erroring. The only way that can fail with the error message you have shown is if you have a misconfiguration in your project, where `UNICODE` is defined <sup>1</sup> but `_UNICODE` is not defined <sup>2</sup>.

<sup>1: as evident by `CString` being mapped to `CStringT<wchar_t>`.</sup>

<sup>2: as evident by the compiler saying `_T("%20")` is a `const char[]` rather than a `const wchar_t[]`.</sup>

`CString` uses `TCHAR` from the Win32 API, not `_TCHAR` from the C runtime library.  *Usually* they are interchangeable, but not so in your situation.  So, you need to either fix your project's configuration so that `_UNICODE` is also defined, or else use the Win32 `TEXT()` macro to match `CString`'s use of `TCHAR`:

```cpp
CString str = TEXT("foo%20bar");
str.Replace(TEXT("%20"), TEXT(" "));
```

Or, simply stop using `TCHAR`-based APIs altogether (`TCHAR` dates back to the days of Win9x/ME when Microsoft was pushing everyone to start migrating their code to Unicode), and really should not be used in modern coding if you can avoid it.  Just use `wchar_t` strings directly instead, eg:

```cpp
CStringW str = L"foo%20bar";
str.Replace(L"%20", L" ");
```

Comment: That's exactly his fourth line of code, which he claims caused a compile error.

Comment: @BenVoigt I didn't see that until after I posted my answer. I have updated my answer with more detail.

Comment: Thank you. ```str.Replace(L"%20", L" ");``` was the solution without fixing the ```UNICODE``` stuff.

Answer (score 3):

The last one should have worked, except that you seem to have a wide CString in a project without the `UNICODE` and/or `_UNICODE` macro defined.

In this combination, the `_T()` macro isn't giving you a compatible string literal.  But `L"whatever"` will.

```
str.Replace(L"%20", L" ");
```

Notice that this does what you asked, but is not adequate for URL unescaping.  You should convert all `%xx` sequences.

Comment: It's still puzzling because in that case the error should be about _T being undefined.

Comment: @anastaciu: `_T()` isn't undefined, it's defined to return the original argument without adding an `L` prefix.

Comment: I see, anyway, out of curiosity I tested it both with and without UNICODE and it works with both, I don't know what to make of it. I also tested it with L prefix and then the error is exaclty what the OP indicated.

Comment: @anastaciu there is a difference between defining `UNICODE` for `TCHAR` (Win32 API) and defining `_UNICODE` for `_TCHAR` (C runtime library).  `CString` uses the former, but `_T()` uses the latter. Using the `L` prefix explicitly will work but only if `UNICODE` is defined

Answer (score 2):

`%20` may be formatted string like `%d`. and `Replace` function return replaced String and str is not replaced.

- try like: `str = str.Replace(_T("%%20"), _T(" "));`
  or
- try like: `str = str.Replace(_T("%20"),_T(" "));`

---

## Extra Info

If you look at this [Format specification syntax: `printf` and `wprintf` functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=vs-2019) article you will see the following clarification:

> A basic conversion specification contains only the percent sign and a type character. For example, `%s` specifies a string conversion. ***To print a percent-sign character, use `%%`**.* ...

Comment: That is what I was going to say! `%` is a prefix for a identifier. So if you want `%` as part of the search text you have top double it as `%%`. I am positive that that is the answer.